# Set Azure App Insights to collect all logs

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

App Insights randomly selects which logs to ignore.
Is it possible to set it to keep all logs?  I need them all.

Answer (score 1):

A short question deservers a short answer :-) You are most likely facing this due to sampling, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling).

> Sampling is a feature in Azure Application Insights. It is the recommended way to reduce telemetry traffic and storage, while preserving a statistically correct analysis of application data. The filter selects items that are related, so that you can navigate between items when you are doing diagnostic investigations. When metric counts are presented to you in the portal, they are renormalized to take account of the sampling, to minimize any effect on the statistics.

The provided link helps you understand what is going on and how to enable/disable sampling.